# How to access the information from a FQL query

Tags: ios, facebook-fql, parse-platform

I've looked on Google for a while on this, but there doesn't seem to be too much information regarding how I can take the dictionary that is returned from a FQL query and save that information to a user for my app. This is the structure of the data that is returned when I query for full name and picture:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            name = "users_name";
            "pic_square" = "https://profile-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-prn2/some_long_identifier_int.jpg";
        }
    );
}
```

Basically, I want to take this result, get the values out of the keys (even though there don't seem to be actual keys and values in this) and save it to my Parse database. I would also like to avoid the un-elegant solution of manually parsing it up by shaving off certain characters. Any help on how people usually do this would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you want to access the name field and fqlresult hold the above data, try

```
fqlresult[@"data"][0][@"name"]
```